# What is user into function Parentheses in symfony php framework?

Tags: php, symfony

When I use

```
php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

to create crud in symfony , symfony give me several functions like

```
public function showAction(user $user)
```

and my Q is what is `user $user`? but url is `/{id}/show`
why we don't use $id in showAction function?
and how user $user works?

Comment: See http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#doctrine-converter

Comment: tnx. but symfony how do this. i want same job with php pure.how can do it?

Comment: Scroll further up the linked page for general symfony. In pure php you’ll have to write the code yourself of course

Comment: The process is called [`Dependency Injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Symfony uses services defined in the container and type hinting to supply the appropriate arguments from the events issued by the kernel. It is very complex and would be best to use a Framework such as Symfony that has been thoroughly tested, as opposed to attempting to developing your own.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism is called ParamConverter.

See the following docs:

[ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)

Comment: Note, the `ParamConverter` is an additional component that allows you to explicitly define the argument conversions, otherwise determined by the default functionality in the [Symfony HtpKernel Component](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/HttpKernel.php#L119)

Answer (score 0):

Typehinting an entity, such as `User`, uses the 'ParamConverter' (from the 'sensio/framework-extra-bundle' Symfony add-in package) to search the database for the primary key - usually the `id` column of the database, and fetch it. If the database table has no such user, it will return a 404 directly, without running any of the user-code. Since it usually would (you've probably linked to it from a previous page), it allows for quickly getting a database record based on the contents of the URL.

You can also create your own ParamConverters for converting other data into something more structured than just a string from the URL - such as making a date in the URL into a DateTime object.